# Ceph: Rados Gateway web endpoint not responding

Tags: ceph, ceph-rgw

I'm creating a simple Ceph cluster and trying to connect to Ceph Gateway.

This is ceph status output of my Ceph cluster:

```
  cluster:
    id:     a7f64266-0894-4f1e-a635-d0aeaca0e993
    health: HEALTH_WARN
            mon is allowing insecure global_id reclaim
            1 monitors have not enabled msgr2
            5 pool(s) have no replicas configured

  services:
    mon: 1 daemons, quorum rhcsa (age 4h)
    mgr: rhcsa(active, since 8s)
    osd: 1 osds: 1 up (since 4h), 1 in (since 4h)

  data:
    pools:   5 pools, 129 pgs
    objects: 27 objects, 453 KiB
    usage:   22 MiB used, 20 GiB / 20 GiB avail
    pgs:     129 active+clean
```

And this is my Ceph config under /etc/ceph/ceph.conf:

```
[global]
fsid = a7f64266-0894-4f1e-a635-d0aeaca0e993
mon_initial_members = rhcsa
mon_host = 192.168.122.61
public_network = 192.168.122.0/24
auth_cluster_required = cephx
auth_service_required = cephx
auth_client_required = cephx
osd_pool_default_size = 1
osd_pool_default_min_size = 1
osd_pool_default_pg_num = 333
osd_crush_chooseleaf_type = 1


[client.rgw.rhcsa]
host = rhcsa
rgw dns name = rhcsa
log file = /var/log/ceph/client.rgw.rhcsa.log
keyring = /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa/keyring
rgw frontends = "beast port=8080"
```

I've created following directories for rgw:
`/var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa`

Then the keyring:

```
sudo ceph-authtool --create-keyring /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa/keyring
sudo chmod +r /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa/keyring
sudo ceph-authtool /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa/keyring -n client.rgw.rhcsa --gen-key   
sudo ceph-authtool -n client.rgw.rhcsa --cap osd 'allow rwx' --cap mon 'allow rwx' /var/lib/ceph/radosgw/ceph-rgw.rhcsa/keyring
```

Then started the Ceph's RadosGW service:

```
sudo systemctl restart ceph-radosgw@rgw.rhcsa
```

RadosGW service seems running fine:

```
[root@rhcsa ~]# systemctl status ceph-radosgw@rgw.service
● ceph-radosgw@rgw.service - Ceph rados gateway
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/ceph-radosgw@.service; disabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) 
   Main PID: 18501 (radosgw)
      Tasks: 9
     Memory: 6.5M
        CPU: 39ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/system-ceph\x2dradosgw.slice/ceph-radosgw@rgw.service
             └─18501 /usr/bin/radosgw -f --cluster ceph --name client.rgw --setuser ceph --setgroup ceph

rhcsa systemd[1]: Started Ceph rados gateway.
```

However, when I try to get a response from 8080, I get nothing:

```
[root@rhcsa ~]# curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
```

I'm using Rocky Linux 9.2, with Ceph version 17.2.6 quincy/stable.

Comment: Please show the output of `ss -tnlp |grep :8080`

Comment: It shows nothing:
```[root@rhcsa ~]# ss -tnlp |grep :8080
[root@rhcsa ~]#
```
 @GeraldSchneider

Comment: Did you check the rgw service multiple times or just once where it appeared to be running? If it failed the rgw logs should provide some pointers why it failed. Is that cluster running package based or containerized? I'm just wondering about Quincy version but you use all those manual commands to create the rgw service and a /etc/ceph/ceph.conf file which is usually replaced by the config db. Anyway, obviously port 8080 is not reachable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreation & reactivating ceph-mgr daemon just solved the problem, now I can get responds from my RadosGW endpoint.